# What does "make something the success it is" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "make something the success it is" mean?

As a language learner, I don't know if the phrase is idiomatic and grammatical.

> 1. These people have **made** the industry **the success it is today**.
> 2. You've all **made** my business **the success it is becoming**.
> 3. You really helped **make** it **the success it proved to be**!

Comment: Why did you type "sth" ?   That is a bad "text-message" abbreviation for "something".  Are you *asking what* "sth" means?   If not, edit the question and please type "something" properly.

Comment: @Fattie I edited the question as you said. But I think using fewer letters is better for searches on the Internet. I see lots of questions have "sth" here (https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=sth ). You can find even some dictionaries (Collins, Longman, etc.) use "sth" in several phrases. And the tag is "phrase-meaning"; how could this be misunderstood? I'm just curious.

Comment: It's an English language site.  Use correct spelling always.

Comment: @Fattie Learners are pretty familiar with the dictionary abbreviations like sth or sb so I don’t know that if we have reached a clear consensus as a community about whether we want to use them or not. It may be worth discussing on [meta]. When I first jumped in here, those abbreviations were off-putting to me too, but they do help us talk about constructions a bit more concisely.

Comment: Hi @ColleenV it would seem there's no need for a consensus on spelling and typos.  (You mention "concise" - no ink is harmed in the making of this page :)  )  No reason to use abbreviations; no reason to use slang.

Comment: @Fattie Abbreviations found in dictionaries are neither incorrect spellings nor slang - it's really just a question of how well understood those abbreviations are in a community. We could want to exclude them because they're a bit too specialized and distracting. I think calling them incorrect is a bit strong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression means that the people (or whatever) in question are in some way ***responsible*** for the success of the company (or whatever). *Success* is used as a noun, and the subject(s) *made* the object into a success.

Your examples are using it correctly.

This is not *make* as in *construct/create* - it is not *I make a child a toy*, in which a toy is being made *for* a child. It is more like *I make a child a scholar*, in that you have caused the child to become a scholar. In that, it is not precisely just the sense of *make* related to *cause*. It is more like *make into*, just the *into* is (sometimes) missing. It thus has elements of both *cause* and *create* meanings.

Comment: Thanks. Then I guess part of it uses the same grammatical structure as "make a child a toy." Is that correct?

Comment: You can think of it that way, though it may lead to a little confusion - there isn't the suggestion that they literally made the company, as in constructed or created it. You could think of it as *made X **into** the success it is*.

Comment: Oh, I've grasped the meaning now. Actually, I have seen examples with "into":  a. "My failures made me into the success I am today." b. "That retailer figured out how to make it into the success it is today, he said." Your comment reminds me of them.

Comment: Essentially, it is the sense of *make* that is related to *cause*, with some shades of the sense *create/construct*, but not at all the sense that is related to *force*.